# Changing the remote repository of git submodule for all commits in git history

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-history

How can I change the remote url of a git submodule without breaking commit history?
Currently if I checkout old commits my submodule seems to have the old remote url witch doesn't exist anymore.

My workflow:

1. Clone repo with commit A,B
2. git submodule update --init
3. Change submudule url
4. Push .gitmodules to remote (Commit C)
5. Clone repo with commit A,B,C
6. Switch to commit A
7. git submodule update --init **-> FAILES**

-> want also the new submodule remote URL, but still the old url in .gitmodules

It seems that `git submodule update --init` is still trying to use the old remote url

If have also tried to use  `git submodule update` , as suggested, but I also got the error:

`The Git repository with name or identifier OLD_REPO_NAME does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try another approach. Instead of replacing URLs in the config files replace URLs on the fly:

```
git config --global url.<NEW-URL>.insteadOf <OLD-URL>
```

See [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) about `url.<base>.insteadOf`.

Comment: ok, this is a manual step that every user of the git repo then has know about, but at least a working approach, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Commits are not tied to remotes. Once you changed a remote the change is in effect for all commits, old and new.

To change the URL for a submodule you need:

- change the URL in file `.gitmodules` in the root of the superproject;
- run `git submodule sync` to copy the change to `.git/config`
- `cd` into the submodule and run `git remote set-url` to change the URL in the submodule.

When you checkout an old commit in the superproject you get old `.gitmodules` but that doesn't matter — `git` doesn't use URLs from `.gitmodules` — it uses URLs from `.git/config`. `git sync` copies the URLs from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`. So after checking out an old commit with an old `.gitmodules` DO NOT run `git sync` and `git` will continue using new URLs from `.git/config`.

Comment: This does not solve the problem  for me. If I clone thre repo and swtich to an old commit in history the .gitmodule file has still the old non existing submodule path. Only commits that where made after I changed the .gitmodules do work

Comment: What exactly is your problem? The question is lacking information. What commands did you run? What error you got?

Comment: Added some more infos, hope that helps

Comment: @User_12399 I added a paragraph to the answer.

Comment: ok, but 'git submodule update --init' still trying to use the old remote url and failes

Comment: `git submodule update --init` calls `git submodule init` which also copies UR:s from `.gitmodules` to `.git/config`. Try `git submodule update` without `--init`.

Comment: git submodule update resutls in `The Git repository with name or identifier OLD_REPO_NAME does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting. `

Comment: After `git submodule update --init` you should fix your `.git/config`